# Changing Levels By Choices

Tags: c#, xna

Hey so I have this code here and what i am trying to do is make 2 more similar levels so when i have tile map 2 and 3 i would have a menu where the player could choose to play on a certain map... i am wondering how i would make this menu, would you please give me some insight on where to begin what type of code i could use etc.

Simple choice menu look:

```
                      Levels

             Level 1

             Level 2

             Level 3
```

and the user would click on it and it would trigger/open one of the tilemaps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace MarsCitadel
{
static class Tilemap

{

#region declarations

    public const int TileWidth = 32;
    public const int TileHeight = 32;
    public const int MapWidth = 50;
    public const int MapHeight = 50;

    public const int FloorTileStart = 0; // 32 x 32 rectangle from sprite sheet
    public const int FloorTileEnd = 3;
    public const int WallTileStart = 4;
    public const int WallTileEnd = 7;

    static private Texture2D texturebarrens;
    static private Texture2D textureroad;
    //static private List<Rectangle> tiles = new List <Rectangle> ();
    static private int[,] mapSquares = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];
    static private Random rand = new Random();

    #endregion

    #region intialization

    static public void intialization(Texture2D tiletexture, Texture2D tiletexture2)
    {
        texturebarrens = tiletexture;
        textureroad = tiletexture2;
        //tiles.Clear();
        //tiles.Add(new Rectangle(0, 0, TileWidth, TileHeight));

        for (int x = 0; x < MapWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < MapHeight; y++)
            {
                mapSquares[x, y] = FloorTileStart;
            }
        }

        GenerateRandomMap();
    }

    #endregion

    #region information about map squares

    static public int getsquareatpixelX(int pixelX)
    {
        return pixelX / TileWidth;
    }
    static public int getsquareatpixelY(int pixelY)
    {
        return pixelY / TileHeight;
    }

    static public Vector2 getsquarebypixel(Vector2 pixellocation)
    {
        return new Vector2(getsquareatpixelX((int)pixellocation.X), getsquareatpixelY((int)pixellocation.Y));
    }

    static public Vector2 Getsquarecenter(int squareX, int squareY)
    {
        return new Vector2((squareX * TileWidth) + (TileWidth / 2), (squareY * TileHeight) + (TileHeight / 2));
    }

    static public Vector2 Getsquarecenter(Vector2 square)
    {
        return Getsquarecenter((int)square.X, (int)square.Y);
    }

    static public Rectangle Squareworldrectangle(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Rectangle(x * TileWidth, y * TileHeight, TileWidth, TileHeight);
    }

    static public Rectangle Squareworldrectangle(Vector2 square)
    {
        return Squareworldrectangle((int)square.X, (int)square.Y);
    }

    public static Rectangle Squarescreenrectangle(int x, int y)
    {
        return Camera.Transform(Squareworldrectangle(x, y));
    }

    public static Rectangle Squarescreenrectangle(Vector2 square)
    {
        return Squareworldrectangle((int)square.X, (int)square.Y);
    }

    #endregion

    #region information about map tiles

    static public int GetTileAtSquare(int tileX, int tileY)
    {
        if (((tileX >= 0) && (tileX <= MapWidth)) && ((tileX >= 0) && (tileX <= MapHeight)))
        {
            return mapSquares[tileX, tileY];
        }
        else return -1;
    }

    static public void SetTileAtSquare(int tileX, int tileY, int tile)
    {
        if (((tileX >= 0) && (tileX <= MapWidth)) && ((tileX >= 0) && (tileX <= MapHeight)))
        {
            mapSquares[tileX, tileY] = tile;
        }
    }

    static public int GetTileAtPixel(int pixelX, int pixelY)
    {
        return GetTileAtSquare(getsquareatpixelX(pixelX), getsquareatpixelY(pixelY));
    }

    static public int GetTileAtPixel(Vector2 pixelLocation)
    {
        return GetTileAtPixel((int)pixelLocation.X, (int)pixelLocation.Y);
    }

    static public bool IsWallTile(int tileX, int tileY)
    {
        int tileindex = GetTileAtSquare(tileX, tileY);
        if (tileindex == -1) return false;
        return tileindex >= WallTileStart;
    }

    static public bool IsWallTile(Vector2 square)
    {
        return IsWallTile((int)square.X, (int)square.Y);
    }

    static public bool IsWallTileByPixel(Vector2 pixelLocation)
    {
        return IsWallTile(getsquareatpixelX((int)pixelLocation.X), getsquareatpixelY((int)pixelLocation.Y));
    }

    #endregion

    #region drawing

    static public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        //int startX = getsquareatpixelX((int)Camera.Position.X);
        //int endX = getsquareatpixelX((int)Camera.Position.X + Camera.ViewPortWidth);

        //int startY = getsquareatpixelY((int)Camera.Position.Y);
        //int endY = getsquareatpixelY((int)Camera.Position.Y + Camera.ViewPortHeight);
        int startX = 0; int endX = 50;
        int startY = 0; int endY = 50;

        for (int x = startX; x <= endX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = startY; y <= endY; y++)
            {
                if ((x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (x < MapWidth) && (y < MapHeight))
                {
                    spritebatch.Draw(texturebarrens, new Rectangle(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }

        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(0 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(1 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(2 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(3 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(4 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(5 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(6 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(7 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(8 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(9 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(10 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(11 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(12 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(13 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(14 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(15 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(16 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(17 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(18 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(19 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(20 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(21 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(22 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(23 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(textureroad, new Rectangle(24 * 32, 7 * 32, 32, 32), Color.White);




    }

    #endregion

    #region map generation

    static public void GenerateRandomMap()
    {
        int WallchancePerSquare = 10;
        int floorTile = rand.Next(FloorTileStart, FloorTileEnd + 1);
        int wallTile = rand.Next(WallTileStart, WallTileEnd + 1);

        for (int x = 0; x < MapWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < MapHeight; y++)
            {
                mapSquares[x, y] = floorTile;
                // if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == MapWidth - 1 || y == MapHeight - 1)
                //{
                //mapSquares[x, y] = wallTile;
                // continue;
                // }

                if (x == 1 || y == 1 || x == MapWidth - 2 || y == MapHeight - 2)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (rand.Next(0, 100) < WallchancePerSquare)
                {
                    mapSquares[x, y] = wallTile;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the Tilemap class abstract, then each version of your map can be a different sub-class of Tilemap (there may be other ways to optimize this, try looking up some design pattern such as "decorator" or "strategy" patterns). Create a Menu class which allows the user to select a map, say with a variety of buttons. Clicking a button should then instantiate the corresponding sub-class of Tilemap, any other code can refer to these objects as Tilemap without knowing which sub-class is implemented.

Comment: Do you know how one could create the menu for them to choose the level, and a code that will trigger once clicked?

Comment: does this not stop the way the game look, my project is a 2d tower defense, here is an image of the tile map:http://gyazo.com/379d1d3ef82cd7bbe1e01e581c1f1365 wouldnt this stop that concept look?

Comment: Why is it necessary to create different classes for a tile map?  A single map class could account for any different layout.  Also it arguably does not answer _"how i would make this menu, would you please give me some insight on where to begin what type of code i could use etc"_.  [Your link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/button.htm) is for a **WinForms** tutorial **not** XNA